# Disable html5 video autoplay

Tags: html, video, html5-video, autoplay

How can I disable html5 video autoplay?

what I've tried:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" autoplay="false" preload="none"><source src="http://mydomain.com/mytestfile.mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

Comment: What browser are you using to view the video in?

Comment: You deleted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19694776/827263) just as I was posting a comment. Did you solve the problem? Unless you're certain the question won't be useful to anyone else, you probably shouldn't delete it.

Comment: @KeithThompson sorry. I thought it won't have any use. undeleted.

Answer (score 71):

I'd remove the `autoplay` attribute, since if the browser encounters it, it autoplays!

`autoplay` is a [HTML boolean attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes), but be aware that the values `true` and `false` are not allowed. To represent a `false` value, you must omit the attribute.

> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

Also, the type goes inside the source, like this:

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls preload="none">
   <source src="http://example.com/mytestfile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

---

References:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/video.html
- [HTML Spec (boolean attributes)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes)

Comment: I tested my code, it doesn't autoplay. Are you sure you are not starting the video via javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure why this didn't work for others, but this was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: Happened to be the only solution that worked for me using a MP4 file that was hosted on AWS. Thanks!

Comment: Facepalmed when this was the solution for mine as well. Had the "autoplay" in and tried everything....looked here...tried....facepalm and thoughts of yelling about wasted hour :)

Comment: This answer is not correct. I'm not sure if the provided link at one point stated that the `autoPlay` attribute is not a type of boolean, but it actually does state it explicitly: "The autoplay attribute is a boolean attribute. When present, the user agent (as described in the algorithm described herein) will automatically begin playback of the media resource as soon as it can do so without stopping." This is similarly noted at W3C Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

Comment: You are right, @myermian. It is a boolean attribute, it's just that the value "false" is set by omitting the attribute, per the spec (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes) . Updating the answer.

Answer (score 12):

remove the autoplay in video tag. use code like this

```html
<video class="embed-responsive-item"  controls>
   <source src="http://example.com/video.mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

it is 100% working

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `autostart="false"` to your source tag.

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" preload="none">
<source src="http://example.com/mytestfile.mp4" autostart="false">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ymV8J/144/)

Comment: Here video is not playing just because it's not having autoplay in Video tag. I am not aware of 'autostart' but I guess it's not helping here.

Answer (score 2):

just use `preload="none"` in your video tag and video will stop autoplay when the page is loading.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed setting `autoplay` to `false` doesn't help some videos will play anyway. See [this case in fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/evuhgfnb/)

You might want to do by code something in the line of if you want to pause all the videos:

```
videos = document.querySelectorAll("video"); 
for(video of videos) {
  video.pause(); 
}
```

Of course the above case will not work if the `video` tag is in a shadow root element, but then hardly any general solution will work with shadow roots elements. There you will need a custom approach and expand first the shadow roots.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove ALL attributes that say `autoplay` as its presence in your tag is a boolean shorthand for **true**.**

Also, make sure you always use `video` or `audio` elements. Do not use `object` or `embed` as those elements autoplay using 3rd part plugins by default and cannot be stopped without changing settings in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

To disable autoplay, you [have to REMOVE `autoplay` attribute completely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video).

Otherwise it will be interpreted as `autoplay=true`. Quite unobvious!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<video class="embed-responsive-item"  controls>
   <source src="http://example.com/video.mp4" autostart="false">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Outdated syntax

Answer (score 0):

I wanted autoplay="false" in edit-mode but autoplay="true" in viewer-mode and solved it by adding the attibute via jQuery only in viewer-mode:

```
<video id="vid" class="my-vid" poster="https://poster-url/poster.jpg"
     loop="loop" controls="controls" width="100%" height="100%">
     <source src="https://video-url/vision.mp4" type= "video/mp4" />
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
        if (document.location.href.indexOf('domain') > -1 ||
            document.location.href.indexOf('test') > -1) {
    
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('video').attr('autoplay','autoplay')
         
            });
        }   

    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set `autoplay=""`

```
<video width="640" height="480" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" autoplay="">
<source src="http://example.com/mytestfile.mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

ps. for enabling you can use `autoplay` or `autoplay="autoplay"`

Comment: Video will autoplay even if we set autoplay="" or autoplay="false", If video tag has attribute autoplay it will autoplay. We can avoid playing video by removing autoplay attribute from video tag.

Answer (score -9):

just put the autoplay="false" on source tag.. :)

Comment: That's what the person originally tried. The answer from @caulitomaz says that it you put the autoplay tag then it plays.