# Prevent autoplay of <video> elements

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari, html5-video

does someone know how to **prevent** Chrome and Safari from autoplaying videos? I am looking for an attribute or style I can incorporate into our website, not a browser extension! We have a few videos on the same page and in Chrome they just all start auto playing for some users while in Safari they kind of autoplay, but they don't start at the same time. They all have sound, so I had expected none of them to autoplay, but apparently that is not the case (at least not for all users).

Thanks!

Comment: I think your question gets answered on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664622/disable-html5-video-autoplay

Answer (score 0):

Use `autostart=0` and `autostart=1`

[HTML embed autoplay="false", but still plays automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20286541/html-embed-autoplay-false-but-still-plays-automatically)

https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0LkA8FoBoleU/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fchrome%2FLkA8FoBoleU

Comment: How can you have both? It feels like this answer requires a bit of additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the `video` or `audio` HTML5 elements, and NOT `object` or `embed`. I also had this problem using the latter HTML elements and the ONLY way to stop them from autoplaying was to change the browser settings. The reason is, because `object` and `embed` use a 3rd party plugin or player when playing your media, while `video` and `audio` are native to the browser.

If you want to stop them from playing anyway on just your box, below are the settings for Firefox:

1. Open up your Firefox Browser, click the menu button, and select "Options"
2. Select the "Privacy & Security" panel and scroll down to the "Permissions" section
3. Find "Autoplay" and click the "Settings" button. In the dropdown change it to block audio and video. The default is just
   audio.